# Propositional Logic - Making sense of a statement without parentheses by using the rules of precedence.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a statement that I need to prove if it is a tautology or give a counter example if it is something else. The problem is there is not a lot of brackets in the whole thing and I can't be sure. I know that rules of precedence helps with these problems and tried that as well, but i can't be sure if I am doing something wrong. 
$$
p \Rightarrow \neg q \equiv (q \not\equiv r) \Rightarrow \neg p \equiv p \Rightarrow \neg r
$$
 I have tried my best to put brackets using the rules of precedence like this:
$$
(p \Rightarrow (\neg q)) \equiv (q \not\equiv r) \Rightarrow (\neg p) \equiv (p \Rightarrow (\neg r))
$$

But then I don't know which part of the equation to try to reduce in order to prove it.  Is that like this
$$
((p \Rightarrow (\neg q)) \equiv (q \not\equiv r)) \Rightarrow ((\neg p) \equiv (p \Rightarrow (\neg r)))
$$
and should i try to take the last version as the statement and try to equate the antecedent$$
((p \Rightarrow \neg q)) \equiv (q \not\equiv r)) $$ to the consequent? $$((\neg p) \equiv (p \Rightarrow (\neg r))
$$

Comment: So what rule of precedence says that implications at the start and end should have precedence over equivalences, but equivalences have precedence over implications in the middle?

Comment: I see your point. But then where should I put the parentheses? $$
(p \Rightarrow (\neg q)) \equiv ((q \not\equiv r) \Rightarrow (\neg p)) \equiv (p \Rightarrow (\neg r))
$$ Would that be true? And if so, how should I go about proving it, I get confused since now I have three parts and don't know which parts to reduce.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you there. I just noticed an inconsistency in your application, but I don't know what precedence rules you are using. Quite frankly, I have a very low opinion of this problem, which I think emphasizes rote application of rules over understanding. Good luck, I hope someone better educated in this matter steps up.